# Get values without using sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using a payment portal in which i need to define a request url in their admin panel. For eg, I need to log in their admin panel and then set my url in which the `pay from xyz` is. As of now my url is `project/:id/contribution/id/payment_method/:type`. Since my url is dynamic, i cant use this url in the admin panel but have to set some static url like `domain/contirbute`

The easy part of having dynamic url is i can fetch project or contribtion from params but if i have a staic url like `/contribute` I will have to depend upon session.

Is there a to get this done without using session?

The funny thing is that , I tired making req with my dynamic url but only after changing the url in the url bar with js but that did nt work too lol.

In the dynamic url page, i have a form which makes a post req to the url given by the payment portal. How does they know form which url is the req comming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way we can solve this problem is by creating two routes. One will be used to render the page which is the static url and the next one will be dynamic url. So when user submits the btn, the user will use ajax to make req with the dynamic url and the origin in the header is still preserved.

I called those payment portal and they had  a checkbox in their own admin panel which could allow to make req from dynamic url